# FadeOut if visible using jquery visible.js

Tags: jquery

I want a div to fade out as soon as it enters the view port

I am using the jquery visible.js pluggin https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible

This is probably a simple fix but I have been stuck for a while now, any suggestions?

```
<section class="section2"><div class="overlay"></div></section>
```

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('section.section2').visible()) {

 $('.overlay').fadeOut(500);
    } 
});
```

Originally I was using this and it was working, however it was glitching on mobile so I just want it to fadeOut and not in again

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('section.section2').visible()) {
// The element is visible, do something
 $('.overlay1').fadeOut(600);
    } else {
 $('.overlay1').fadeOut(600);
// The element is NOT visible, do something else
  }
});
```

Comment: please provide more details about issue.

Comment: Issue is that it's not working once I removed 'else'

Comment: What was the `else` that you removed?

Comment: question updated to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an event listener to do this, you should use [Intersection Observer (IO)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this. With IO you can check when elements come into viewport (or overlap with each other) and react to it, depending on how many percent they overlap.

First, you have to specify your options for IO to which parameters you want to listen:

```
let options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

Since you want to react to an element being visible 100%, use threshold of 1.0

Next step is you specify the element you want to watch:

```
let target = document.querySelector('.section2');
observer.observe(target);
```

Last step is to define what should happen once the element is visible:

```
let callback = (entries, observer) => { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element
  });
};
```

```js
let options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}


let callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      $(entry.target).find('.overlay').fadeOut();
    }
  });
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
let target = document.querySelector('.section2');
observer.observe(target);
```

```css
.h100 {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.section2 .overlay {
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="h100">
</div>
<section class="section2">
  Watch me stay 
  <div class="overlay">
    Watch me disappear
  </div>
</section>
<div class="h100">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! Is there any reason it wouldn't work on .section2's child div?

Comment: what do you mean it won't work on section2 child divs? added some example html to my fiddle, it is possible. Or did i understand something wrong?

Comment: I made a fiddle of your code and it doesn't work if you set a height for .section2 or if you target a class inside .section2

Comment: It works when I set a height for section2. And I don't get what you mean with target a class inside section2, i'm targeting the overlay class inside section2. So please update your question to include `all` requirements and don't drip feed them to us.